# inserting the values in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$brand_name = $bd - > execute("brand_name", "*", "1 order by brand_name asc");
for ($i3 = 0; $i3 < count($brand_name); $i3++) {
    $bd - > insert("search", "page_title,page_description,page_url,image_id", "'Partners','{$brand_name[$i3]['brand_name']}',
        'http://xyz.in/demo/partners.php?search='".$brand_name[$i3]['id']."','{$brand_name[$i3]['uniq_id']}'");
}
```

I am using execute function to run a query ie `SELECT * FROM BRAND_NAME ORDER BY BRAND_NAME ASC`
and then I am inserting it into the search table 
So my problem is during inserting , when inserting this  **`'http://xyz/demo/partners.php?search='".$brand_name[$i3]['id']."'`**  , I when I see my mysql table that column only shows this part only  **`http://xyz/demo/partners.php?search=....`**
I am not able to understand why its not showing my id .

Comment: is `execute()` doing the equivalent of fetch-array?

Comment: @AlanKaelBall no its equivalent to mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: are you sure your script is going in the for loop? like is your execute returning values? And if it is like mysql_fetch_assoc so it is returning only 1 row

Comment: Try to assign the "http://xyz.in/demo/partners.php?search=".$brand_name[$i3]['id'] it to a variable and print output for correctness

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a single statement to do an insert based on a SELECT, rather than multiple inserts using the values returned from the results of a select?

```
INSERT INTO search (page_title, page_description, page_url, image_id)
SELECT 'Partners', brand_name, CONCAT('http://xyz.in/demo/partners.php?search=', id), uniq_id
FROM brand_name
```